# C++ read number from a file

Tags: c++, file

I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    ifstream infile("argv[1]");
    int testNumber = 0;
    infile >> testNumber;
    cout << testNumber << '\n';
}
```

I run it with this command `./program myfile.txt`

`myfile.txt` contains some integers separated by spaces and new lines

I'd expect the program to output the first number in the file, but instead it always prints `0`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ifstream infile("argv[1]");
```

Looks for a file named `argv[1]`, not `myfile.txt`. To use the program arguments, remove the quotes:

```
ifstream infile(argv[1]);
```